# I want a easily understandable code to pick a set of rows from a table based on todays date

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner, I am trying to show a list of employees attendance based on the date say today. I need a code example for the above condition, i tried a lot of methods but none is of my use, I will provide the table structure. Kindly guide me with a step by step procedure, I am really a patience guy.

```
Table: empatten
================

empid
empname
empstatus (whether present or absent)
doa (date of attendance)

This is my show blade
=====================
@extends ('empatten.layout')
<html>
<head>
<title>Display attendance information</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route

('empatten.index') }}">Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead>

<tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>Emp Name</th>
<th>Emp Status</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>
@foreach($empatten as $attens)

 <tr>
     <td>{{ $attens->empid }}</td>
 <td>{{ $attens->empname }}</td>
 <td>{{ $attens->empstatus }}</td>
 <td>{{ $attens->doa }}</td>

</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>

This is my Index Page:
=========================

@extends('empatten.layout')
@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Employee Management Page</h2>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('empatten.create') }}"> Add Todays Attendance</a>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('empatten.show') }}"> View Todays Attendance</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

This is my controller show function
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

 public function show(Empatten $empatten)
    {
        return view('empatten.show',compact('empatten'));
       //->with('empatten', empatten::all());    

    }
```

Comment: _“Kindly guide me with a step by step procedure”_ - please go read [ask]. We are not here to give you full-on _tutorials_. You are expected to learn the basics of the techniques you are using on your own. We can help you with _specific_ questions, but this is just too broad and open-ended. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner, out of interest, I framed such a big one... Anyway thanks for your advice

Comment: What *specifically* is the problem that you face? Do you get an error (please specify), don't you get any results, do you get wrong results (why are they "wrong")?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
    $employee_attendance = YourModelName::whereDate('doe', Carbon::today())->get();
Here YourModelName is the Your model for empatten table

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method according to your need.. here `\Carbon\Carbon::now()` getting the todays date ..

```
public function show()
    {
        $empatten = Empatten::where('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
        return view('empatten.show',compact('empatten')); 

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable method. I am using the below code in the index.blade when I click the "View Todays Attendance", I am receiving 404 not found error.  The code is : <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('empatten.show', 'empatten')  }}"> View Todays Attendance</a>

Comment: 404 means there is no route defined